# Make as much as possible of buffer visible in window instead of showing empty space after buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

It is possible to "scroll past the end of the buffer" in a window.  This is useful because Emacs has to somehow use the extra space when the buffer does not fill the whole area available to the window used to display it.

However sometimes when the whole buffer would fit completely into the window the top part still isn't displayed and more space than necessary is wasted below the buffer content to fill the available space. It would be better if the window were automatically scrolled to show the complete buffer or if it is bigger than the window as much as possible.

In other words the only time when a window displays something "below the buffer end" is when the window is to big.

Is there a mode or option to do that?

[image]

Comment: How to fix a typo in a screenshot? :-)

Comment: There is noting you can do about it.

Comment: How do you get the line numbers to the left?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance built-in linum-mode or nlinum-mode from gnu elpa don't remember which I turned on.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout I hope you're talking about the typo not the wasted space.

Comment: Thanks you. And another ?, What do you use to get the column showing end of buffer, beginning of buffer and the "More buffer above window" arrow?

Comment: Yes ;-) The typo being "noting" instead of "nothing" on line 14.

Comment: ... and that wasn't even the typo which I spotted oO

Comment: @ShannonSeverance indicate-buffer-boundaries, there is more in custom group fringe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** So something like this?

```el
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-eob-recenter)
(defun my-eob-recenter ()
  (when (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-max))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (recenter -1))))
```

**Original answer:**

If you have a window which is larger than its contents and you want to shrink it to fit, there's a binding for that.

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> runs `shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer`

Personally I suspect this would be annoying if it happened automatically, but you might try this:

```el
(defadvice split-window (after my-split-window-shrink)
  "Shrink the selected window after a window split
if it is larger than its contents."
  (shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer))
(ad-activate 'split-window)
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I don't want to resize the window I just want the window to display as much of the buffer as possible. The window should "behave the same at the bottom as at the top", unless the window is "bigger" than the buffer, in which case the top of the buffer should always be visible.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. So in your example screenshot the top window is actually fine, and it's just the position of the text in the bottom window that you have an issue with? Basically, you want a an option to never display any vertical space after the last line of a buffer?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I was hoping for. We will see how it holds up in practice. I have upvoted your answer but will wait with accepting it; I am still hoping for a polished mode that also takes care of special cases. But thanks a lot! That already helps quite a bit.